# Would it be fine if I applied for a business Schengen visa for a conference but spent most of my time for tourism?

Tags: schengen-visas, tourist-visas, business-travel

So currently my company is planning to have a conference in the Czech Republic and as a person who needs to have a Schengen visa, I would need to apply for it at the Czech Republic Embassy.

Unfortunately there is no Czech Embassy in my city. I would need to travel to another city + apply there + stay there until I got my visa, which costs a lot of money.

So I was thinking, since I'm going to spend money anyway to go to this event, would it be fine if applied for a business visa for another Schengen Country?

I would then travel to that country and spend a week before finally going to my company's conference.

For example:

- Apply for a Schengen visa at the Austrian embassy.
- Travel to Austria and stay there for a week as a tourist (7 days).
- Then travel to Czech for the conference and also leisure after the conference is over (6 days).

NOTE:
I will spend more time in Austria than Czech just so that I can fulfill the condition to apply at the Austrian embassy. Otherwise I would need to apply at the Czech embassy.

Comment: Is your main *purpose* of travel the conference, or tourism?

Comment: I need to go to the conference, even though I spent most of my time outside the Country where the conference is being held. So I guess main purpose is Conference ? but Considering I'm spending more time on Tourism then Business, you can also said that my main purpose could be for Tourism. Not sure how to answer this question

Comment: Would you be applying for a visa at all if you weren’t going to the conference? There are lots of questions on this site from people planning to add some tourism time to a business trip, typically they’re not doing that to get around an inconveniently located embassy. Austria *might* see it that way.

Comment: If there's no conference then I wouldn't be going in the first place

Comment: the issue in my case on why I prefer not to apply on the embassy on another city are 
1. I need to fly to this other city ( So a plane ticket )
2. I need to rent an accommodation until I got my Visa (this will cost a lot)
factoring this 2 things, I found that its cheaper to just get Schengen Visa for another country and while I'm in that Schengen country, I might as well enjoy it there. The main reason I'm applying this is for the Conference, if there's no conference then I would be applying for the visa and go there at all

Comment: Would your employer be willing to pay for the extra costs to apply at the right embassy and have you looked into getting the passport send back to you rather than staying?

Comment: No I asked my employer about that, but they won't cover it. As for getting the passport sent back, I don't want to risk losing my passport as I need the passport for another trip 2 weeks after the conference ( I have experiences courier losing my package couple of times)

Comment: Seems odd that an employer is expecting an employee to attend a conference in another country but won’t cover the associated costs of said employee getting the visa they need in order to be able to go.

Comment: Yes, I was asking that question too. They will cover my Visa fee, Plane ticket fee to Czech but not the accommodation and travel fee for getting Visa

Comment: There is no such thing as a business visa, only short-stay visas and that's what you will be applying for. So whether you should apply for a business or tourism visa is a red herring. Even if VFS or some online forms make it difficult, what you are supposed to do is simply to check both *tourism* and *business*. All this is mostly unrelated to *where* you should apply.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question in your subject line is 'yes.' The answer to your plan is 'no.'

You are supposed to apply for a visa from the **main destination** of your trip. All other things being equal, the main destination is where you spend the most time, but when you combine a business conference and some rest and sightseeing, that business conference is your main destination.

- Example: You plan on one week at the beach in France, and two weeks climbing mountains in Italy. Italy is your main destination, since tourism is tourism and Italy is the longer period.
- Example: You plan on two days attending a wedding in Netherlands, and three days sightseeing in Germany. *The Netherlands are your main destination,* because your itinerary is determined by that wedding.
- Your Example: You spend six days on business in Czech Republic, and seven days on tourism in Austria. *The Czech Republic is your main destination,* because your itinerary is determined by that conference, and because for most people business is more important than leisure.
- Example: You spend a month on the beach in Spain, and in between a day in France on business. You can probably argue that Spain is the main destination, because one day does not determine your month-long tourism.

Answer (score 0):

Got my visa: I ended up just getting a tourist visa. Much easier than a business visa.

Comment: Please review Relaxed's comment to your original question. There is no "business visa" or "tourist visa." in the Schengen area. In Schengen, there is only the short-stay visa. I'm glad your application was successful, but you'll do better long-term if you accept the Schengen view of visas.